# Node JS - pull VAR out of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I trying to scrape data off a website. What is returned to me is an array that looks like.

```
var $ =  cheerio.load(body)
```

returns:

```
{ [Function]
  fn:
   { constructor: [Circular],
     _originalRoot:
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        attribs: {},
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: null } },
  load: [Function],
  html: [Function],
  xml: [Function],
  text: [Function],
  parseHTML: [Function],
  root: [Function],
  contains: [Function],
```

The child object is what I'm after so...

```
var obj = $.root()[0]
```

returns:

```
{ type: 'root',
  name: 'root',
  attribs: {},
  children:
   [ { data: 'var usdata_real = {     // All_data node opens\n\n\tATL: {     // Country tag opens\n\t\tid: "ATL",\n\t\t\tdata: {     // Data node begins\n\t\t\tq1_1980: 169.304888373489,\n\t\t\tq2_1980: 164.585093140904,\n\t\t\tq3_1980: 166.167521028595,\n\t\t\tq4_1980: 163.
....
```

I want the 'data' in this array.

```
obj = obj['children'][0]['data']
```

returns:

```
var usdata_real = {     // All_data node opens

        ATL: {     // Country tag opens
                id: "ATL",
                        data: {     // Data node begins
                        q1_1980: 169.304888373489,
                        q2_1980: 164.585093140904,
                        q3_1980: 166.167521028595,
                        q4_1980: 163.040844286677,
                        q1_1981: 163.31019903107,
                        q2_1981: 162.449966027231,
                        q3_1981: 158.719442789479,
                        q4_1981: 162.744884934737,
.....
```

which is ALMOST perfect. Except it returns to me an array which is no bueno. I want to be able treat this as an object so i can do something like

```
obj['ATL']
```

and get they KEY/VALUE pairs.

So my question....

Is it possible to strip out the object in this array ('var usdata_real'). Because that is what I'm after.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: usdata_real is an object in your 'returns' code example. I don't see any arrays.

Comment: obj['usdata_real'] returns 'undefined'

obj[0] returns 'v'
obj[1] returns 'a'

Comment: looking a bit closer now, it is because it's a string inside of the returned value. still not an array.. `{ data: 'var usdata_real = {` you will have to evaluate/parse that to get your object.

Comment: thanks all for the feedback!

I will have to look into eval. I have not used that before.

Comment: if the data coming back is just data and contains no circular refs or functions you can strip off the `var usdata_real = ` and just JSON.parse the rest into an object.

Comment: thanks for advice. though parsing doesnt work.

undefined:3
        ATL: {     // Country tag opens
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token A
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be using Cheerio as intended. Providing the HTML would have been nice so someone can show you how to use the library correctly rather than entertain a likely [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).